# Elements of Arraylist Colliding cause game to freeze. Searching for a Better way?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to make this simple android game where the player shoots bullets to kill the enemy. I have an ArrayList of Bullets and an ArrayList of enemies

The problem is when the Bullet hits the enemy the app freezes(not every time colisions happens) for about second. I can imagine that removing the dead enemy from the list and rearraging the others consume alot of memory. But am not sure if thats the reason!. I got the collision method:

```
  public boolean collision(GameObject a, GameObject b) {
    if(Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(), b.getRectangle()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And than using this in the update method like this:

```
     //loop through every enemy and check collision and remove
    int i ;   
    for ( i = 0; i < enemys.size(); i++) {
        //update enemy
        Enemey e = enemys.get(i)
         e.update();


       for (int j = 0 ; j < bullets.size() ; j++ ){
            Bullet b = bullets.get(j) ;
            b.update();
            if (collision(e , b)){
                enemys.remove(i); // When this
                bullets.remove(j);  // and this are commented ,its all ok
                break;
            }
        }
            //remove enemy if it is way off the screen
        if (enemys.get(i).getX() < -300) {
            enemys.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better, more effective way to check for collision ?
Thanks

Comment: Short note you could change your collision method to `return Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(), b.getRectangle())`

Comment: `if (enemys.get(i).getX() < -300)` could throw an error in case the bullet did hit the last enemy on the list by removing it the list is smaller and `.get(i)` would throw an `ArrayOutOfIndexException`

Comment: where are you calling this code?

Comment: Can you try (at least for debugging) updating the `Bullet` and `Enemy` object's (lets say inActive) flag instead of removing from the list and see if there is a performance change?

Comment: @Nordiii That does happen. I Think i saw that happening with the Exception. I ll check it out. Thanks

Comment: @PravinSonawane I made a 'GamePanel' Class and in it an Update method. Am calling player, background, bullets updates in it.